# php artisan migrate failed

Tags: php, laravel

I have reinstall my ubuntu 1.04.3. First of all I installed php: 7.2.19, nodejs: 12.10.0, apache and mysql. After that I installed gloabally the composer and some php extentions that said that were needed to install Laravel and finished with the installation of laravel. I created a project with the command Laravel new ... When I try to do "php artisan migrate" I take this error and I dont know what to do.

Error:
*

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)
>
> at
>   /home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665

```
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669|
```

Exception trace:

> 1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
>         /home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> 2
>   PDO::__construct("sqlite:/home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel/myProject/database/database.sqlite",
>   [])
>         /home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.
>   *

.env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:aG05wMCXTkKQeBdTAZBGzjvyfY8gyhPmZs4qoKIiYU4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

config/database.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Are you sure that pdo_mysql (the extension) is installed ?

Comment: Yes it's installed

Comment: can u give the config/database.php file ?? i think your error is in 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', ' '), is in this portion

Comment: config/database.php file is the default which is created by the laravel. .env the same but if you want it: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: From the stack trace it seems that a PDO object using sqlite is instantiated `sqlite:/home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel/myProject/database/database.sqlite`. Why is that since you have Mysql selected as the db ? Can you check on that?

Comment: I was trying to solve the probelm and I tried to change mysql to sqlite but it didnt work.I returned the project to the default settings. It doesnt show the warning for the sqlite anymore. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to install the missing php extension.

```
apt install php-mysql
```

Comment: I tryied it but I have the same result

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue !!! 
I was using sqlite (DB_CONNECTION=sqlite) in my project and came across this error while integrating that.
Run command this command to check what dependencies are installed on your php server

```
php -m
```

This will list all the dependencies that are installed. Check that pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite and sqlite3 are installed or not. If not install those.
Make sure your have enable pdo extensions in ubuntu.

In my case, sqlite was not install for my php 7.2. So if thats the same with you run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite
```

Just to make sure it works restart apache server too by running this command:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Then run migrate command in your laravel project:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

your database seems to be using **sqlite**

```
sqlite:/home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel/myProject/database/database.sqlite",
```

try changing the .env property `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` to `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite`